# JAVA - Cross application authentication

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, authentication

I have different java web applications running on tomcat as different modules and one java web application as an addon running on the same tomcat server as another different module. I want to use the addon within the different applications (which essentially appears as a popup and is just one javascript file with a few URL-mapped controllers at the back end).
 I have allowed cross domain requests for the addon within the Tomcat realm, so the applications can access the popup and retriece the data.

```
Eg. in WebApp1, [http://localhost:8080/page1.html]:

ajaxGet(http://localhost:8081/getPopup, function(html){
    showPopup(html);
});
```

The architecture of all applications is a simple JSON based request-response driven UI with javascript at the front end and URL-controller/servlet mappings on the JAVA-backend.

It works fine, but of course, it will also work for any requests from within the applications in the realm even if they are not authenticated. ie, even from the login page, I can request the popup.
How shall I take care of the authentication? Considering the addon doesnt need to be connected to the database for separate authentication, its authentication depends on whether the calling application is already authenticated or not.

Thanks in advance for your inputs. :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need *authorization*, which usually depends on *authentication*. Authentication is the process of telling the service who is making the request, while authorization is the process of deciding if the principal is allowed to make the request.

The first thing you should do anyhow is adding authentication and authorization to the service which makes the popup content (`/getPopup`). Once you have secured that service, you actually have a number of choices:

- implementing some single-sign-on framework
- employing a federated authentication technology
- forwarding requests from the calling application with a custom authentication scheme
- ...

Obviously, the simplest solution would be shipping everything together in a single deployment unit.

As a side note, mind the cookie session name when testing on localhost: cookies are bound to the hostname, not hostname + port, so the JSESSIONID issued by one service at `localhost:X` will be overwritten by the JSESSION id of `localhost:Y`

Comment: Hey Raffaele,
Thanks a lot for your reply. I will implement a **custom authentication scheme** because it is not possible to add the popup project across all the various applications, it costs more time and effort. And, single-sign-on is not possible because some of the applications are LDAP authenticated and some are by the normal spring security database-based authentication. 
Thanks! 
would appreciate any ideas for the authentication scheme while i try my own ideas. :)

Comment: If the popup doesn't need to interact with the host application, then instead of static HTML you can expose a mini-application which  can handle login via AJAX and call it via `<script src="http://localhost:8081/popupApp.js"></script>`. It can even export a function `showPopup()` so you can call it from the host application when an event is triggered. This would be the simplest solution if applicable because it doesn't need users mapping/sharing - and doesn't even use cross-origin requests

Comment: I just used an illustration for the showpopup here in my question, the ajax request actually receives a rendered javascript function as a response, which is exactly what you suggested.
I am planning to have a pre-handshaked authorization token which will only be set when the calling applications are authenticated. Passing this token within the request to the popup will be used to accomplish the authentication.
Will keep you posted! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad it helped! Anyway, returning a function is not what I suggested. What I suggested is writing a self-contained application, say popup.js, and including that in your host application with a `<script>` element. This way you don't need cross-application authentication